# R Shiny: Table Created Using Latex Is Messy

Tags: r, latex, shiny

I am new to Shiny as well as Latex.

I am using the following script to crate a table output in Shiny.

## ---

```
library(xtable)

ui <- shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
                withMathJax(),
                titlePanel("Panel Title"),
                sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                                checkboxGroupInput("inputs", label = "Select Inputs:",
                                                   choices=c("Option A",
                                                             "Option B"),
                                                   selected="Option A")),
                        mainPanel((tabsetPanel(
                                tabPanel("Test Table",h2("Test Table Header"),uiOutput("tabletest"))))))))

server=function(input, output) {output$tabletest<-renderUI({ 
        table2=data.frame(A=c("{SubheaderA}","Item A1","Item A2","Item A3","{Subheader B}"," Item B1","Item B2","Item B3"),
                          B=c("","Value  A1","Value  A2","Value  A3","","Value  B1","Value  B2","Value  B3"))
        test=print(xtable(table2,type="latex",sanitize.text.function=identity))
        html=paste0("$$",test,"$$")
        list(tags$script(src = 'https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/2.0-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML', type = 'text/javascript'),
             HTML(html)
        )  
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## ==

Would anyone be to help me with figuring out why I am not able to print tables.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to this: [Tabular in MathJax?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/tabular-in-mathjax), the `tabular` environment is not supported in MathJax. Is there some reason you thought it was?

Comment: Possible alternative: https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/LaTeX-Tabular-environment